# Change font color in cell based on value in a cell to the right

Tags: excel

I need a rule to change font color in all cells in column A for which value in cell to the right (in column B) is 0.

I am trying to use conditional formating rule like this:

`=OFFSET(?,0,1,1,1)=0`

but I don't understand how to get a reference `?` to "this" cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use OFFSET here. Just a simple rule based on the formula `=B1=0`, or if (as I assume) you want to ignore blank cells in column B, the formula `=AND(B1<>"",B1=0)`.

[image]